# Обновлять блок после ответа от сервера

Tags: html, jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Делаю динамический фильтр. Нужно чтобы по выбору селекта отправлялся пост запрос к серверу, а при успешном получении ответа - обновлять контент без перезагрузки всей страницы.

Раньше в других проектах я делал это с помощью load() но теперь,не могу реализовать подобное...

Нашел инфу про вывод из эксплуатации данного метода, может быть поэтому и не фурычет.

**@Controller:**

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public Model doFilter(@RequestParam String status, @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC, size = 5) Pageable pageable, Model model){

    IdeaStatus ideaStatus = IdeaStatus.getValueByName(status);

    Page<Idea> ideas = ideaRepository.findAllByStatus(pageable, ideaStatus);

    model.addAttribute("ideas", ideas);
    model.addAttribute("pageable", pageable);

    return model;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ideas">
            <div id="ideas">

                <!-- Idea -->
                <div class="card" th:each="idea : ${ideas}">
                   // something code
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
    function send(formData, url){
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "html",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(res) {
            $(".ideas").load("#ideas") // Здесь необходимо обновлять содержимое блока
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `success: function( htmlCode ) { $(".ideas").html( htmlCode ); }`. `htmlCode` - это то будет то, что вернул запрос по `url`

Comment: `htmlCode`  о котором говорит князь, это `res` в вашем случае

Comment: Докопал: $(".ideas").html($('.ideas', res).html())

Answer (score 0):

```
    success: function(res) {
        $(".ideas").html($('.ideas', res).html())
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]